# Using sparklyr on local RStudio with an apache cluster

Tags: apache-spark, rstudio, sparklyr

I'm new to Sparklyr and fairly new to R.  I'm trying to figure out if I can run sparkly on my local RStudio and connect to an apache spark cluster on the network.  All the blog examples talk about running RStudio Server directly on the apache spark cluster.  Can anyone validate if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

You likely want to use Livy unless your laptop is physically very close to your cluster. See https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr#connecting-through-livy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should be possible.
First of all - make sure that your cluster is accessible from your local PC.
If yes, go to your Spark cluster's Spark Master web console (ip_address:8080) to get the Master's URL ("spark://...").

```
library(sparklyr)
# Set your SPARK_HOME path
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="path/to/spark_home")
config <- spark_config()
# Optionally you can modify config parameters here
sc <- spark_connect(master = "spark://paste_your_spark_master_url:7077", spark_home = Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), config = config)

# Some test code, copying data to Spark cluster
iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris)  
flights_tbl <- copy_to(sc, nycflights13::flights, "flights")
batting_tbl <- copy_to(sc, Lahman::Batting, "batting")
src_tbls(sc)
```

You may also want to try to run Spark locally. Just follow the instructions on sparklyr webpage: http://spark.rstudio.com/. Just maybe use newer Spark version (e.g. 2.0.2).